# How to derive entropy transport equation from heat equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Suppose I have heat equation:
$$
\rho (\partial_{t} + (u \cdot \nabla)) T = -\nabla \cdot \mathbf R,
$$
where $\mathbf R$ - some vector and $T$ - temperature.

How to get the equation for entropy $S$ in form of
$$
\tag 2 \rho T(\partial_{t} + (u \cdot \nabla ))S = -\nabla \cdot \mathbf R
$$
from $(1)$?

It seems that I need to use some thermodynamical relations like
$$
dT = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_{V}dS + \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S}dV,
$$ 
and then to transform derivatives $\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_{V} = \frac{T}{c_{V}}$, $\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S} = -\frac{T}{c_{V}}\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_{V}$, but I don't know how to get an explicit form of $(2)$.

Edit. For getting it, I've returned to definition of temperature, $T \equiv \langle \frac{m(\mathbf v - \mathbf u)^{2}}{2}\rangle = E$. Then by using relations
$$
dE = Tds - pdV = TdS + \frac{p}{\rho^{2}}d\rho , \quad \partial_{t}\rho + \nabla (\rho \mathbf u ) = 0
$$
I've got an equation for entropy.

Comment: What do $u$ and $\mathbf R$ mean? Without knowing the meaning of the symbols, there is no way to derive one from another. The first equation is not a common heat conduction equation.